# .click() function doesn't work javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE:

Somehow the just work fine after I tried it..

UPDATE

I'm using `.click()` function on my javascript, but it doesn't work.

Here is my JS code:

```
src="jquery.js";
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
var institutionID, acadCareerID;
$(document).ready(function(){


    getInstitution();

    institutionID = $( "select#institution option:checked" ).val();
    if(institutionID == null){
        institutionID = 1;
    }

    getAcadCareerByInstitution(institutionID);

    acadCareerID = $( "select#acadCareer option:checked" ).val();
    if(acadCareerID == null){
        acadCareerID = 1;
    }

    getPeriodByAcadCareerAndInstitution(acadCareerID);
    getDepartmentByAcadCareer(acadCareerID);



    $("select#institution").change(function(){
        institutionID = $( "select#institution option:checked" ).val();
        getAcadCareerByInstitution(institutionID);
    })
    $("select#acadCareer").change(function(){
        acadCareerID = $( "select#acadCareer option:checked" ).val();
        getPeriodByAcadCareerAndInstitution(acadCareerID);
        getDepartmentByAcadCareer(acadCareerID);
    })


    $("div#search").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        console.log("abc");
    });

});
```

all functions like `getInstituion()`, `getAcadCareerByInstitution(institutionID)` etc are ajax call.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="doInsertSchedule" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="institution">Institution</label>
                    <select name="institution" class="form-control" id="institution">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="acadCareer">Academic Career</label>
                    <select name="acadCareer" class="form-control" id="acadCareer">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="period">Period</label>
                    <select name="period" class="form-control" id="period">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="department">Department</label>
                    <select name="department" class="form-control" id="department">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Deadline Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="deadline" placeholder="Deadline Date" name="deadline">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <div id="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</div>
            </form>
```

I already put jquery for my Master Layout (Laravel 5)

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url()}}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url()}}/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">        
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{url()}}/js/tools.js"></script>
        <script src="{{url()}}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>BINUS - @yield('title')</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</head>
```

I want the Search Button / Div to do something when I click. I can't see what's wrong here.

I already tried `<div>` to `<button>` but it just will work like submit. I also already tried to put `event.preventDefault()` at my JS code, but it didn't work too.

Comment: It seems your HTML loaded via ajax call, it append to document after event listener click on `#search` element already registered.

Comment: [There is nothing wrong with the code you've shown](https://jsfiddle.net/ut5j18m6/). Something else is the problem, such as not including jQuery.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I already put jquery library at my JS code and Master Layout (Laravel 5).

Comment: @WillySandi Please provide an example in your question. It's not really possible to help if the shown code doesn't have the problem your describing (*It would also make this off-topic*).

Comment: @PigBall yes, my <select>(s) are loaded via ajax. but i just append <select> at my form, not entire form

Comment: Ensure your document have only one element with `id="search"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but have you added a jquery library before your script?

Secondly, if you did and the items on the page are loaded after the document has loaded you will need to change your code up, for instance:
Give your form an id

```
<form action="doInsertSchedule" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postForm">
```

Then in your jquery script

```
<script>
$('#postForm').on('click', '#search', function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    console.log("abc");
});
</script>
```

The above will allow the javascript to run on items that are bought in after document load, however it is important you set it on a parent element that is avaiable at document load

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your solution, but it didn't work too. I already have jquery library at top of JS code, and also put it at my Master Layout (Laravel 5)

Comment: It should definitely be functioning then, it is just the text "Search" that when you click it will activate yeah? Also in your browser can you open the console (f12 to open developer tools, then select Console item), then check if any errors are appearing there for your script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with event delegation...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").on("click", "#search", function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        console.log("abc");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works OK. You need to write the jquery library in the final, just before of `</body>`

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

Example it works ok!: [Example Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PabloCordova/9uns0ccd/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
<div id="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</div>
```

This looks like it will render on the page as two buttons. Your ID here is attached to the div, not to the button, they should both appear to look like buttons providing bootstrap is loaded, but only the div with "search" as the content will do anything.

This is the only thing that appears odd, the only other problem is you are not loading your jquery as stated elsewhere.